# How to access the currently touched instance of the Prefab?

Tags: unity, c#

I have a prefab which is instantiated in the Scene and what I am trying to do is to disable with a *touch* or `timeCounter` but sometimes it disables all the instances of the prefab and sometimes 2 or 3 of them.

I want to disable particular object which I have touched currently.

when i am passing the *collider* in `Destroy(hit.collider)` it works perfect but how to handle it *null* is passed as parameter.

Here is my code:

```
 void Update () {
     blastingTimeCounter -= Time.deltaTime;

     if (blastingTimeCounter <= 0) {
         DestroySquare (null);
     }

     for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++) {
         if (Input.GetTouch (i).phase == TouchPhase.Stationary) {
             hit = Physics2D.Raycast (Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (
                 Input.GetTouch (i).position), 
                 Vector2.zero);
             if (hit.collider != null) {
                         DestroySquare (hit.collider);
             }
         }
     }
  }

  void DestroySquare(Collider2D collider){

     if(collider == null)
     {

     }
     else{
     collider.gameObject.SetActive (false);
     blastingTimeCounter = blastingTime;
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally find out the solution and it works..

```
 void DestroySquare(Collider2D collider){

 if(collider == null)
 {
      GameObject obj = (GameObject)gameObject;
        obj.SetActive (false);



      //blastingTimeCounter = blastingTime;  this was changing in all the instances of a prefab 

    obj.GetComponent <BlackSquare2>().blastingTimeCounter = blastingTime; // correct




 }
 else{
 collider.gameObject.SetActive (false);
 //blastingTimeCounter = blastingTime;  this was changing in all the instances of a prefab

  collider.gameObject.GetComponent <BlackSquare2>().blastingTimeCounter = blastingTime; // correct


       }
}
```

I Just want to know why `blastingTimeCounter = blastingTime` is changing in all the instances of a prefab?

while doing this  `collider.gameObject.GetComponent <BlackSquare2>().blastingTimeCounter = blastingTime;` it will reset `blastingTimeCounter` correctly.

Comment: because when you write blastingTimecounter it means it happens on all the Monobehaviours and when you do collider.gameObject.GetComponent<>, GetComponent returns the instance of the class that is running on this specific game object.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is something like this:

```
void DestroySquare() {

    if (hit != null) {
        hit.transform.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    } else {} // Do nothing
}
```

Comment: this works perfect but when 'hit' != null , but at some condition i also want to disable it  when hit == null, then what to do in that case?

Comment: when i am doing gameObject.setActive(false) in else statement as you have mentioned, it disables all the game object in the scene.

Comment: @user3191102 Are you sure you're doing `hit.transform.gameObject`?

Comment: yes it works but i am asking how to do the _else_ part when _hit_ is _null?_

Comment: If I'm correct, I don't think you need to do anything in the else statement? If `hit` is null it usually means that the raycast didn't hit anything.

Comment: at some time when there is no touch i am disabling it with a _blastingTimeCounter_  passing _null_ to `DestroySquare(null).`

Comment: A better option, @user3191102, would be to write a separate function that handles the time-up scenario when you *do* want to disable the objects but *don't* have a raycast hit.